# Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException [Symfony 2.4]

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am using a custom controller which all my other controllers will extend instead of Symfony's basic controller class.

Everything works fine in prod env except for one route (which works fine on localhost btw).

Here is the route that causes this exception:

```
acme_change_lang:
    pattern:  /changeLang/{locale}/
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Acme:changeLang}
```

CoreController:

```
class CoreController extends Controller
{
    private $_locales;

    public function __construct() {
        //if set to true then the language is active. False means the language cannot be used at the moment.
        $this->_locales = array('en' => true, 'fr' => true);
    }

    .....

    protected function getRefererRoute(Request $request = null)
    {
        if ($request == null)
            $request = $this->getRequest();

        //look for the referer route
        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
        $lastPath = substr($referer, strpos($referer, $request->getBaseUrl()));
        $lastPath = str_replace($request->getBaseUrl(), '', $lastPath);

        $matcher = $this->get('router')->getMatcher();
        $parameters = $matcher->match($lastPath);
        $route = $parameters['_route'];

        return $route;
    }

    protected function setSession(Request $request, $loc = '') {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if (empty($loc) OR !isset($this->_locales[$loc]) OR $this->_locales[$loc] == false)
            $loc = 'en';
        $session->set('locale', $loc);
    }

    public function changeLangAction(Request $request, $locale) {
        $this->setSession($request, $locale);
        return ($this->redirect($this->generateUrl($this->getRefererRoute($request))));
    }

   .....
}


[2014-11-15 18:54:14] request.INFO: Matched route "acme_change_lang" (parameters: "_controller": "Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Controller\AcmeController::changeLangAction", "locale": "en", "_route": "acme_change_lang") [] []
[2014-11-15 18:54:14] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: "" at /home/fakePath/www/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php line 66 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException:  at /home/fakePath/www/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:66)"} []
```

The thing I don't understand is that it says it has found a matching route and then throws that exception.

Any ideas about what is causing this ?

Comment: IT throws resource not found, which has nothing to do with route not found. We won't be able to help you if you remove all paths in that error message

Comment: None of the paths have been removed from the error message. I' ve just change the application and bundle names thats it.
EDIT: and the "fakePath" is just the websites name

Comment: Apart from the mismatch in the _controller value, does the message really say: `Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: ""` (note the empty resource path)?

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I don't understand it either

Comment: Is is possible that the referrer is empty in prod env (headers stripped by web server or other reason), leading to an empty lastPath value, hence causing the matcher exception ? Apart from that, that looks like a complicated way of changing the language

Comment: @David Actually referer is correct but the base url is always empty. Kind of strong.
Any ideas why ?

Comment: Any rewriting from a load balancer or other system that intercepts/forwards the request to the actual webserver?

Comment: Not really. As I said, my controller extands CoreController (which contains these methods) so nothing else is done before the changeLangAction is called. I'll try to give you more details when I get home this evening.